# Best way to select values that start with symbols

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have category ( title ) start with alphabetical A

```
$sql = "select * from category_data WHERE category LIKE 'A%'";
```

And is working, but how I can select from database the `category ( title )` which don't start with `[A-Z]` or `[1-9]` just with symbols

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM category_data WHERE ASCII(UPPER(LEFT(category,1))) IN(...)
```

You can pass allowed [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters in your `IN` clause.

If you want to **skip** specific range, you can use `NOT BETWEEN x AND y;`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) function of MySQL like as

```
SELECT * FROM `category_data` WHERE `category` REGEXP '^[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

Comment: Since it's the title and he only wants to check first letter then `a-z` should be removed from your regular expression and only left `A-Z0-9` because first letter of title should always be upper case.

Comment: Yep that can be the case but I've placed all of those possibilities that can occur over here @KuKeC

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the 1st character isn't in the alphabet or a number like:

```
$sql = "select * from category_data WHERE substr(category,1) NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%' AND substr(category,1) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use REGEX

```
 $sql = "select * from category_data WHERE category NOT REGEXP '^[^A-Z0-9]'";
```

This will give you the category name which does not start with A-Z and 0-9

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM category_data WHERE LEFT( category, 1 ) NOT IN ('a','b','c')
```

//add the rest of char in your IN list

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you do not want to use regex

```
SELECT * FROM category_data WHERE 
    (LEFT(category, 1) NOT BETWEEN 'a' AND 'Z') AND
    (LEFT(category, 1) NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 9);
```

`LEFT(category, 1)` grabs first character of your `category` column and confirms that it is not between `a-z` or `0-9`.